# How to pass encypted values to jmx properties

Tags: java, jmx

We have our app running using jmx properties , which are passed in the command line arguments while starting the app as systempropties.
There are couple of properties which are having plain text passwords

```
-Djmxremote.password having file contains plain text passwords.
-Djavax.net.ssl.keystorePassword
-Djavax.net.ssl.TrustStorepassword.
```

I have my own encryption logic and am passing a encrypted values to them. Now I want to understand if we decrypt in the code those propertis and set them back to the systemproperties,  how can we make jmx to pick the latest values.
Any leads on this is much appreciated.